# Test if null for a sharepoint column with C# in a dynamic field of the mapping tool layer2 cloud connector

Tags: c#

I use the layer2 cloud connector synchronisation tool to synchronize between a sql database and a sharepoint database on the right side. When synching from right to left (from SP to SQL) in a datetime field "dl date" there can be empty values. I established a dynamic column in the tool, which should return "01.01.1753" if in SP "dl date" was empty or just the regular date if it was not empty. That's due to our SQL database, which doesn't accept empty values but has to have this weird "01.01.1753" as empty value.
In the definition of the dynamic field I use the following C#-Code:

```
 if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(NächstesFSKontrolldatum.ToString())) {  
 return DateTime.Parse("01.01.1753"); } else { return
 NächstesFSKontrolldatum; }
```

But no matter how I compare the field "NächstesFSKontrolldatum" (aka "dl date") if it's null, it doesn't fire the part of the condition for beeing null.

When the tool finally writes just the date to sql there is an error which says can't put string '' into date field. I guess that always my second case of the condition fires and he tries to write just empty values into the database.

Because this code runs inside of the layer2 tool, I don't know how to debug or write to the console. Maybe you know or it's not possible?

Do you know, which comparison I have to make?

Andreas

Comment: When the tool finally writes just the date to sql there is an error which says can't put string '' into date field. I conclude, that always my second case of the condition fires and he tries to write just empty values into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is beter test if the 'NächstesFSKontrolldatum' can be parsed with a TryParse

```
DateTime testDate;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(NächstesFSKontrolldatum.ToString(), out testDate)) 
{  
    return DateTime.Parse("01.01.1753"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    return testDate; 
}
```

This way you're sure the value returned can be readed as a Date

Comment: Thanks @J.Salas , I tried this but it still evaluates always to the second part of the condition.

Comment: the second part of my condition returns a valid date _for sure_.  Could you have an XY problem and your SQL DB cant parse the data format that you're sending?

Comment: okay I understand. But I get the following error when synching:

-> An error occurred while executing connection 'Copy of Driver_SQL_to_SPO': The type of field 'DL Checking Date' in table 'SQL_DRIVER' was changed from 'System.String' to 'System.DateTime'. Since there is no conversion method to convert the value '', the metabase could not be adjusted accordingly. If you intend to set up a new connection, it is recommended to duplicate the existing connection

It seems that he wants to write '' into the field

Comment: I tried that in a copy of an original synchronisation set. In this copy we already tried some massaging of the data within the select statement to set the column as string. But that didn't work. It seems, that the synching still assumes the column in the SQL as string. I tried my above approaches in the origining synching set and there it worked out better. The only little problem is, that I can't write "1-1-1753 12:00:00 AM" into the column. I tried DateTime.Parse(). I think I will figure it out now.